# Fitting data in polar coordinates

Tags: fitting

I have some data in polar coordinates:

```
datar = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/CM7Rj6jC", "Table"];
datar1 = Rescale[datar[[All, 2]]];
datar2 = Rescale[datar[[All, 3]]];
plot2 = ListPolarPlot[{datar1, datar2}]
```

[image]

I want to fit the two curves to the equation: $r=A\cos^{2}\left(t+\phi\right)$, where $t$ is the angle and $A$ and $\phi$ are constants to be determined for each curve. How can I find those constants and overlay the fitting to the data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Addition:**  95% confidence bands for the mean added.

```
(* Convert from degrees to radians *)
datar = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/CM7Rj6jC", "Table"];
datar[[All, 1]] = 2 π datar[[All, 1]]/360;

(* Fit curves *)
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[datar[[All, {1, 2}]], a Cos[t + ϕ]^2, {a, ϕ}, t];
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[datar[[All, {1, 3}]], a Cos[t + ϕ]^2, {a, ϕ}, t];

(* Plot results *)
mpb1 = Table[Flatten[{t, nlm1["MeanPredictionBands"]}], {t, 0, 2 π, π/50}];
mpb2 = Table[Flatten[{t, nlm2["MeanPredictionBands"]}], {t, 0, 2 π, π/50}];
Show[ListPolarPlot[{datar[[All, {1, 2}]], datar[[All, {1, 3}]]}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]],
  PolarPlot[{nlm1[t], nlm2[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}],
  ListPolarPlot[{mpb1[[All, {1, 2}]], mpb1[[All, {1, 3}]], 
    mpb2[[All, {1, 2}]], mpb2[[All, {1, 3}]]},
    PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dotted}, {Blue, Dotted}, {Orange, Dotted}, {Orange, Dotted}}, Joined -> True]]
```

[image: Data and fit with 95% confidence bands for the mean]

Comment: If I wanted to set the zero degrees on top, should I make 2 π (datar[[All, 1]]-90)/360 ?

Comment: And keep the counterclockwise direction?  Does that mean your data was taken with zero degrees meaning 90 degrees?  In other words, what measurement system characterized the angles you have?  Or do you just want to now rotate the data?

Comment: I just want to rotate the the result plot so that the zero is on top and it increases clockwise. In my data, zero degrees is still the initial point.

Comment: Also, I might need to rescale the plot, making it bigger to combine with another plot.

Comment: Both of those requests constitute a new question.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to Jim's proposal is to directly use the definition for least-squares fitting:

```
datar = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/CM7Rj6jC", "Table"];
datar[[All, 1]] = datar[[All, 1]] °;

d1 = Drop[datar, None, {3}]; d2 = Drop[datar, None, {2}];

{a1, φ1} = NArgMin[Norm[Function[{θ, r}, a Cos[θ + φ]^2 - r] @@@ d1], {a, φ}]
   {0.530572, -0.584595}

{a2, φ2} = NArgMin[Norm[Function[{θ, r}, a Cos[θ + φ]^2 - r] @@@ d2], {a, φ}]
   {0.472955, 0.969005}

{Show[PolarPlot[a1 Cos[θ + φ1]^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}, PolarAxes -> True], 
      ListPolarPlot[d1, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 4]]], 
 Show[PolarPlot[a2 Cos[θ + φ2]^2, {θ, 0, 2 π}, PolarAxes -> True], 
      ListPolarPlot[d2, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 4]]]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: fitted polar curves]